# Where does Raphael.js store an element's data that is set with the element.data() method?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've got a bunch of Raphael element objects on a canvas and have associated data with each, like so:

```
element.data('dataVal',x);
```

In the above example, I'd like to know where x is stored. I've been looking through the source for Raphael.js and have zeroed in on this section:

```
elproto.data = function (key, value) {
    var data = eldata[this.id] = eldata[this.id] || {};
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        if (R.is(key, "object")) {
            for (var i in key) if (key[has](i)) {
                this.data(i, key[i]);
            }
            return this;
        }
        eve("raphael.data.get." + this.id, this, data[key], key);
        return data[key];
    }
    data[key] = value;
    eve("raphael.data.set." + this.id, this, value, key);
    return this;
};
```

So, my hunch is that 'eldata' is a property of a Raphael paper object and that 'eldata' contains objects for each Raphael element, and it is in these objects that the data are stored.

In essence, my question is: Once I've created a Raphael canvas, added elements, and added data to those elements, how would I access the data (without using a Raphael function)? I've tried simple stuff like looking for R.eldata (where R is a Raphael canvas), but that wasn't fruitful.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eldata` is [a local variable](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/v2.1.0/raphael.js#L382) defined within a closure (line numbers on the left from v2.1.0):

```
 233|  (function () {
....|
 254|      var loaded,
....|
 382|          eldata = {},
....|
2396|      elproto.data = function (key, value) {
....|
2413|      elproto.removeData = function (key) {
....|
3743|  })();
```

Because it's enclosed, it can only be accessed by a function defined within that same closure. So, you will have to use Raphael's `data` and `removeData` methods to access it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's a *local* variable.

Comment: @RobW True. I just figure "private" makes the point of "inaccessible" better than "local" does. Still, updated.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm relatively new to Javascript. For my own learning, is eldata in scope for methods of Raphael paper objects or just element objects (or both?). My general confusion centers around the point that this wrapper function where eldata is declared runs only once -- so then is there only one instance of eldata per Raphael canvas object created (in scope for all elements) OR is there an instance of eldata for each element on a given canvas? Thanks.

Comment: @AlR. There's only 1 `eldata` defined at all -- it's the same object for all instances. However, keys/properties of `eldata` are created and retrieved per unique `id` -- `eldata[this.id]`.